# Getting Error 18451: Only, or Error: 17810 when making multiple calls to database

Tags: sql-server, typeorm

I'm new to SQL Server. I was a postgres user before. I installed the default SQL Server on my local machine and I'm trying to get an old react with node js application of mine working with a SQL Server. When ever my frontend makes more than 1 call to the backend, if my SQL Server has admin privileges it throws

> Error: 17810: Could not connect because the maximum number of '1' dedicated administrator connections already exists.

If not, it throws:

> Error 18451: Only administrators may connect at this time.

I checked my database configs and it's set to `MULTI_USERS`, so I don't understand why I can't login without admin privileges. Can someone help me with this? I wasn't able to find anything online.

My NodeJS backend is using TypeORM to connect to the database

Answer (score 1):

The [dedicated administrator connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver15) is a different *kind* of connection. It's not just "a connection being made by someone with administrative access". You would use the DAC when the SQL instance is having some kind problem, and you can't connect at all because resources are all tied up. SQL will reserve some resources especially for the DAC connection to make sure you can still connect.

A DAC connection can be made by specifying `ADMIN:` as part of your connection string, which will connect to the assigned DAC port.

You shouldn't use this for "routine" admin work. Just connect using a login with the required administrative server roles (eg, sysadmin). You *definitely* shouldn't use this as part of a regular application's connection string. You shouldn't be using a SQL Server sysadmin login either. Create a user with the appropriate permissions for your application, and don't use the admin connection.

Regarding your second issue: Make sure the instance wasn't set to start in single user or minimum configuration mode using [startup flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-ver15). Note that this is for the whole instance, it's not the same as the configuration for an individual database.

Comment: I checked my start up flags and they are the following:  -d -e -l so its supposed to allow connections other than admin. The only reason why i gave the user admin privilages was bc its not allowing me to connect otherwise.

Comment: I will try to figure out what my connection string is, since it's being generated by typeorm I don't know if they are putting the ADMIN: on it